# Rails Mailchimp API integration with Gibbon Gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mailchimp

I'm trying to include the MailChimp Api for an Email form with the Gibbon gem in rails.

Adding a mail etc works and I see the correct callbacks from the API in the console, but except for the success case, where it changes the email id div correctly, **nothing happens.**

It just seems that the case switch doens't work or it can't read the code that comes back from the api.

Routes etc. are set correctly.

Here's my Controller:

```
 class MailchimpformController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def submit
    mailchimp_api_key = "mysecretapikey"
    mailchimp_list_id = "mysecretlistid"
    g = Gibbon.new(mailchimp_api_key)
    response = g.list_subscribe({:id => mailchimp_list_id,
                                :email_address => params[:email],
                                :double_optin => false,
                                :send_welcome => false})

    if(response.is_a?(Hash))
     puts response
    case response['code']
     when 502
      @js_email_error = "Invalid Address!"
     when 214
      @js_email_error = "Already signed up!"
     else
      @js_email_error = response['error']
    end
      @js_email_success = nil
    else
      @js_email_success = "Thanks!"
      @js_email_error = nil
    end
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js
    end
    end
  end
```

It only works when it adds a fresh email to the list.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag submit_path, :class=> "form", remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, :class => 'email', :type=>"email", :placeholder => 'Sign up for beta testing' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Absenden", :alt => "Absenden", class: "input-btn"%>
<% end %>
```

and the javascript stuff submit.js.erb

```
<% if @js_email_error %>
$("#email").val("<%= @js_email_error %>");
<% end %>
<% if @js_email_success %>
$("#email").val("<%= @js_email_success %>");
<% end %>
```

I'm also receiving a `Completed 500 Internal Server Error` for POST /mailchimpform/submit with the (correct) Callback from the MailChimp API. And I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay now it works. the error was caused by the error handling of gibbon (setting)

with

```
g.throws_exceptions  = false
```

before the submit it now works correctly.